# writing functions without using helper function such as fold_left

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

```
let rec ddr l =
  let (r,_) =
    List.fold_left (fun (a_l, a_i) x ->
        ((a_i + x) :: a_l , a_i+x))
      ([],0) l in
  List.rev r
```

I haven't learned `List.fold_left` or `List.rev`, but the code above solves my task, which is:  write a function that does

```
  [1;2;3] -> [1; 3; 6]
  [4, 5] -> [4; 9]
```

Comment: It's probably easiest if you give your recursive function a second parameter for the accumulator.

Comment: Can you write a recursive function that takes a list and returns another list with each value incremented by one? If yes, please show us - that code is a good start.

Comment: @Bergi Yes I think I can write it. I wrote the recursive accumulated version with the help from a friend but I still don't understand it. do you mind showing me the non-accumulated version of the code I uploaded? and possibly explain both of them if you don't mind??

Comment: You can (should) simplify by omitting the line `|[x]->[sx+x]`. Try to understand why the other cases are enough and how they would handle a single-element list.

Comment: How did your friend arrive at this solution, maybe he can explain it? And what do you mean by "*the non-accumulated version of the code*"?

Comment: @Bergi we can omit it because it's tail recursive right? the answer is accumulated. non tail recursive version, I think non tail recursive version is easier to undrstand

Comment: No, your version is not tail recursive, and omitting the second case has nothing to do with tail recursion.

Comment: @Bergi okay thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a homework problem straight from the course I'm teaching this term! So I won't give the solution, but I'll give you a hint.

Suppose you're processing a list `[1;2;3;4]` and you've reached the `3`. If only you knew what the partial sum of the preceding elements were, then it would be easy to compute the new partial sum. Try to find a way to carry the partial sum so far with you, perhaps by using a helper function.